# Align 2 layers in PS by similar "points"

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, alignment

I have two different photos from the same place. One is old from the 80's and the new one from the current time.

What I'm trying to achieve is to fit the photos over each other. 
I'd like to align the new photo to have the portrayed object at the exactly same place as from the 80's. I have no idea what kind of lenses, films or cameras was used years in the old photo.

The `Auto-align layers` doesn't work in Photoshop as the photos are too different so for now I'm using `free transform` and the `wrap` feature which is useful but not great.

I would like to select a couple of points from layer X (the old photo) and assign these to other points in a second layer (the new photo). Then hit some magic button and witchcraft will happen.

New photo: 
[image]

Old photo:
[image]

Thanks for any help and cheers!

Comment: Take a look at [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net). It's an open source panorama stitcher which can align images based on control points you can define yourself. I've only used the software a few times so I can't give you a more extensive answer.

Comment: hmmm panoramic software might be a way... I've never thought about that. Actually my last idea was to set vector layer in QGIS, load two JPGs and set points and do a geo reference process :] I'm quite familiar with Hugin and yes, sounds like a hard and annoying possibility but it might do this. Worth to try it :]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is perspective, which is different in the two shots.

The older image was taken with a tilt-shift lens or a view camera, and the photographer slightly overcompensated: the sides of the building diverge from bottom to top. In the newer shot, the camera was tilted up, giving the more usual converging lines on the building sides.

My approach here would be to take both images into the Lens Correction filter and correct those lines so they are vertical in both shots, then use scaling to get them to match.